# Consume SQS messages from Celery

Tags: python, amazon-sqs, django-celery

I have a Celery implementation in my Python application. The broker i am using is SQS. The messages which goes to SQS are from a different application via Boto3's send_message() api. Now my confusion is how to trigger Celery to pick the message from SQS to process. There will be some task which will run in Celery which should process messages from SQS right. My requirement is similar to [Celery Consumer SQS Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801289/celery-consumer-sqs-messages).

As per my understanding, Celery polls SQS till messages arrives there. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Wondering if you could run Celery tasks with `boto3`. I'm trying the same and even started and issue/question in boto3 github repo[1]. In the meanwhile I'm using Celery itself to start the tasks from remote clients:

```python
app = Celery(broker='sqs://access_key:secret_key@sqs_server:9324')
app.send_task('tasks.my_task', args=[1], queue='my_queue')
```

  [1]: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2037

Answer (score 1):

I call this task every 20 seconds:

```
@app.task(name='listen_to_sqs_telemetry')
def listen_to_sqs_telemetry():
    logger.info('start listen_to_telemetry')
    sqs = get_sqs_client()
    queue_url = 'https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxx'
    logger.info('Using ' + queue_url)

    keep_going = True
    num = 0
    while keep_going:
        keep_going = False
        try:
            response = sqs.receive_message(
                QueueUrl=queue_url,
                AttributeNames=[
                    'SentTimestamp',
                ],
                MaxNumberOfMessages=5,
                MessageAttributeNames=[
                    'All'
                ],
                WaitTimeSeconds=20
            )
            # logger.info(response)
            if 'Messages' in response:
                keep_going = True
                for rec in response['Messages']:
                    # Process message
                    sqs.delete_message(
                        QueueUrl=queue_url,
                        ReceiptHandle=rec['ReceiptHandle']
                    )
                    num = num + 1
            else:
                pass
                # logger.info(response)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(str(e))
    logger.info('done with listen_to_sqs_telemetry')
    return "Processed {} message(s)".format(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, try to run the worker as daemon. Use tool like supervisord to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For my uses, I opted to create an separate AWS Lambda function to receive the events and forward them to the Celery worker (via a different queue).

I've used variations of this pattern a few times to forward data to celery workers for processing.

- Webhooks from 3rd party services make requests to Lambda function URLs
- S3 bucket event notifications
- Cognito user event hooks

The following example receives events from S3 on new file uploads:

- Includes the celery library (so I don't have to worry about maintaining the celery message structure myself).
- An empty method declaration with the same signature as the method in the worker, annotated with the celery task annotation.
- The handler unpacks the input message, and triggers the task.

```py
# - Env vars set:
#   - `CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT` = 'sqs' (could inline, this is always the same)
#   - `CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE` = 'celery-queue' (name of the sqs queue configured to use with celery)

import os
import logging
from celery import Celery, shared_task

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info('Loading function')

app = Celery('triggers')
app.config_from_object(os.environ, namespace='CELERY')


@shared_task(name='on_new_file_uploaded')
def on_new_file_uploaded(records):
    '''
    The signature needs to match the task found in celery worker, but the
    implementation exists there.
    '''
    pass


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        logging.info('Posting file uploaded action')
        on_new_file_uploaded.delay(event['Records'])
        logging.info('Posted file uploaded action')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception('Error handling message for {}.'.format(event['Records']))
        raise e
```